# Reading input from .txt file with different kinds of delimiters

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to read a .txt file and retrieve x and y coordinates, a city ID, and city name.

```
[1, 1]-3-Big_City
//expected : x = 1,  y = 1, city_ID = 3, city_name = Big_City

[2, 8]-2-Mid_City
//expected : x = 2,  y = 8, city_ID = 2, city_name = Mid_City
```

How do I read and store the `x`, `y`, `city_ID`, and `city_name`

I have a while loop that can print out the whole line, but I do not know how to delimit using the unwanted symbols to get the required values.

```
while(getline(inputFile, aLine))
{
    getline(inputFile, aLine, '[');
    x = aLine;

    getline(inputFile, aLine, ',');
    y = aLine;

    // stuck here has getline 3rd parameter only accepts character and not string
    getline(inputFile, aLine, ']-');
    city_ID = aLine;

    ....

    cout << x << " " << y << " " << city_ID
}
```

The output I get is also not what I expected. The first line would be missing and the others are not shown.

Comment: Can you format your question so we can see the exact contents of the txt file? Is it those lines that start with [1, 1] and [2, 8] respectively? Edit: Thanks Quentin for the formatted edit.

Comment: I apologise. This is my second time asking a question here.

Comment: You could use [`ignore`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) to skip those chars. Or use regex: https://ideone.com/I3T2ER

Comment: @Johnny Mopp using your code, 

----------------------------------------------
std::cout << "x = " << m[1] << ", "
               << "y = " << m[2] << ", "
               << "city_ID = " << m[3] << ", "
               << "city_Name = " << m[4] << std::endl;-------------------
How should i store the values?
x >> m[1];
y >> m[2];...

or 

x >> m[1] >> y >>m[2];

im asking cause im not familiar with regex

Comment: @MistaJ I updated the code to use variables. And just for fun, here's a version using `ignore()`: https://ideone.com/z63U5C

Comment: The text file only has ----------------------------------
[1, 1]-3-Big_City
[2, 8]-2-Mid_City
-----------------------------------------------------------I added in the comments to illustrate the values i want to retrieve

Comment: Could the X, Y, and city_ID be more than one digit in some records?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing difficult about parsing a complex line to obtain the needed information from it, you just approach it the same way you would eat a whale -- one byte at a time...

In your case, since you are coordinating 3 integers and a string for each record of city data (e.g. `x, y, id` and `name`) it makes sense to declare a simple `struct` to coordinate the differing types of data as one object. That allows you to store all data in a `vector` of `struct`. Here, you could use something simple like:

```
struct data_t {         /* simple struct to coordinate data for each city */
    int x, y, id;
    std::string name;
};
```

To read you data, the easiest approach is to open the file, and then read each line of data into a string. You then have that string to parse your data from. Converting the string into a `stringstream` is helpful as it allows you to treat your line of data as a stream making use of `>>` as well as `getline` in various successions to get the wanted information from the line.

To get the information from the stringstream created from the line, let's look at an example of what needs to be done to get the information you want starting with the line contained in the stringstream:

```
[1, 1]-3-Big_City
```

Within the read loop we will read values into a temporary `struct` and if everything parses correctly, we will add that temp struct to your vector of struct. The temp struct can be:

```
        data_t dtmp;                    /* temp data struct */
```

To get your `x` value, you need to remove the `[` leaving `"1, 1]-3-Big_City"` in the stringstream. The key is the ***validate*** each step. To remove the `[` you can use:

```
        /* read/discard [ */
        if (!getline (ss, stmp, '[')) {
            std::cerr << "error: invalid format before - x.\n";
            continue;
        }
```

Now read the `1` directly from the stringstream into `dtmp.x` validating that the integer conversion succeeded:

```
        if (!(ss >> dtmp.x)) {      /* read x from stringstream */
            std::cerr << "error: invalid format - x.\n";
            continue;
        }
```

Since the read stops at the first non-integer character in the stringstream, you are now left with `", 1]-3-Big_City"`. Since `>>` will skip leading whitespace, all you need to do to prepare for reading your `y` value is remove the `','` and then read you `y` value into `dtmp.y`:

```
        /* read/discard , */
        if (!getline (ss, stmp, ',')) {
            std::cerr << "error: invalid format before - y.\n";
            continue;
        }
        if (!(ss >> dtmp.y)) {      /* read y from stringstream */
            std::cerr << "error: invalid format - y.\n";
            continue;
        }
```

(**note:** since you know that you only need to remove a single character, you can read a character with `ss.get()`, but to be consistent you can continue with `getline` and a delimiter -- entirely up to you)

After reading the `y` value, you are left with  `"]-3-Big_City"` in the stringstream, so your next task is to strip through `'-'` to expose the `id` for reading. At this point it should be obvious that you can basically repeat what we have done above all the way down the line to read the rest of the values. For `id`, let's do:

```
        if (!getline (ss, stmp, '-')) { /* read/discard - */
            std::cerr << "error: invalid format before - id.\n";
            continue;
        }
        if (!(ss >> dtmp.id)) {     /* read id from stringstream */
            std::cerr << "error: invalid format - id.\n";
            continue;
        }
```

Leaving `"-Big_City"`, and again, either `ss.get()` to strip the `'-'` or continue with `getline` as we have done above:

```
        if (!getline (ss, stmp, '-')) { /* read/discard - */
            std::cerr << "error: invalid format before - name.\n";
            continue;
        }
        if (!(ss >> dtmp.name)) {   /* read name from stringstream */
            std::cerr << "error: invalid format - name.\n";
            continue;
        }
```

That's it. Your data is now parsed into the temp struct `dtmp` and all you need to do to store the data in your vector is:

```
        data.push_back(dtmp);   /* add temp struct to vector of struct */
```

Placing the above in a loop will allow you to parse all data in your file into your vector of struct. As you progress in your programming, and begin using classes for objects like city data, you will find you can even overload the `>>` operator to take care of all that is done above and you need only provide the open file stream and your overloaded input function will do the rest. (that's left for another day)

A short example reading your data file could be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct data_t {         /* simple struct to coordinate data for each city */
    int x, y, id;
    std::string name;
};

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    if (argc < 2) { /* validate argument given for filename */
        std::cerr << "error: filename required as 1st argument.\n";
        return 1;
    }

    std::string line;           /* string to hold each line read from file */
    std::vector<data_t> data;   /* vector of struct data_t to hold data */
    std::ifstream f (argv[1]);  /* open filename given for reading */

    while (getline (f, line)) {         /* read each line of file into line */
        data_t dtmp;                    /* temp data struct */
        std::string stmp;               /* temp string for parsing */
        std::stringstream ss (line);    /* create stringstream from line */

        /* read/discard [ */
        if (!getline (ss, stmp, '[')) {
            std::cerr << "error: invalid format before - x.\n";
            continue;
        }
        if (!(ss >> dtmp.x)) {      /* read x from stringstream */
            std::cerr << "error: invalid format - x.\n";
            continue;
        }

        /* read/discard , */
        if (!getline (ss, stmp, ',')) {
            std::cerr << "error: invalid format before - y.\n";
            continue;
        }
        if (!(ss >> dtmp.y)) {      /* read y from stringstream */
            std::cerr << "error: invalid format - y.\n";
            continue;
        }

        if (!getline (ss, stmp, '-')) { /* read/discard - */
            std::cerr << "error: invalid format before - id.\n";
            continue;
        }
        if (!(ss >> dtmp.id)) {     /* read id from stringstream */
            std::cerr << "error: invalid format - id.\n";
            continue;
        }

        if (!getline (ss, stmp, '-')) { /* read/discard - */
            std::cerr << "error: invalid format before - name.\n";
            continue;
        }
        if (!(ss >> dtmp.name)) {   /* read name from stringstream */
            std::cerr << "error: invalid format - name.\n";
            continue;
        }

        data.push_back(dtmp);   /* add temp struct to vector of struct */
    }

    for (auto& d : data)    /* output all stored data */
        std::cout << "x: " << d.x << "  y: " << d.y << "  id: " << d.id
                << "  name: " << d.name << '\n';
}
```

**Example Input File**

```
$ cat dat/xyid.txt
[1, 1]-3-Big_City
[2, 8]-2-Mid_City
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/citydata dat/xyid.txt
x: 1  y: 1  id: 3  name: Big_City
x: 2  y: 8  id: 2  name: Mid_City
```

Look through everything and make sure you understand what was done. If you have questions, just ask in a comment below.

Answer (score 1):

And now the next approach. This is using Object Oriented idioms and modern C++ algorithms.

We have data and methods which belong somehow together. For this there are classes (structs) in C++. So you can define a class, with member variables and methods, which can work with the class varaibles. Everything works as one object.

Additionally. The class knows, how to read or print its values. And only the class should know that. This wisdom is encapsulated.

And, next, we want to search interesting data embedded somewhere in a string. The string contains always a certain pattern. In your case your have 3 integers and one string as interesting data and some delimiters in between, whatever they are.

To match such patterns and search for interesting parts of a string, C++ has `std::regex`. They are extremely powerful and hence a little bit complicated to define.

In the below example I will use `const std::regex re(R"((\d+).*?(\d+).*?(\d+).*?([\w_]+))");`. This defines 4 groups of submatches (in brackets) and something in between. So any delimiter, space or whatever is possible.

If you want to be more strict, you can simply change the pattern and you can detect errors in the source data. See `const std::regex re(R"(\[(\d+)\,\ (\d+)\]\-(\d+)\-([\w_]+))");`. This is a more strict approach. The inputfile will not be read in case of error. Or only the beginning with the valid data.

Please see below example:

```
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ios>

std::istringstream testFile{ R"([12, 34]-56-Big_City1
[789 , 910 ] - 11 -  Big_City2
(55; 88} + 22 *** Big_City3
[77, 666]-555-Big_City4)" };



const std::regex re(R"((\d+).*?(\d+).*?(\d+).*?([\w_]+))");


struct CityData
{
    // Define the city's data
    int xCoordinate{};
    int yCoordinate{};
    int cityId{};
    std::string cityName{};

    // Overload the extractor operator >> to read and parse a line
    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, CityData& cd) {

        // We will read the line in this variable
        std::string line{};                 

        // Read the line and check, if it is OK
        if (std::getline(is, line)) {

            // Find the matched substrings
            std::smatch sm{};
            if (std::regex_search(line, sm, re)) {
                // An convert them to students record
                cd.xCoordinate = std::stoi(sm[1]);
                cd.yCoordinate = std::stoi(sm[2]);
                cd.cityId = std::stoi(sm[3]);
                cd.cityName = sm[4];
            }
            else {
                is.setstate(std::ios::failbit);
            }
        }
        return is;
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const CityData& cd) {
        return os << cd.xCoordinate << ' ' << cd.yCoordinate << ' ' << cd.cityId;
    }
};

int main()
{
    // Define the variable cityData with the vectors range constructor. Read complete input file and parse data
    std::vector<CityData> cityData{ std::istream_iterator<CityData>(testFile),std::istream_iterator<CityData>() };

    // Print the complete vector to std::cout
    std::copy(cityData.begin(), cityData.end(), std::ostream_iterator<CityData>(std::cout,"\n"));

    return 0;
}
```

Please note: `main` contains only 2 statements related to CityData. The class knows how to operations should be done.

And, because I cannot use file on SO, I read the data from "std::istringstream". This is the same as reading from a file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet:

```
struct city_t {
    int x;
    int y;
    int city_ID;
    string city_name;
};

int main()
{
    ifstream file("person.txt");
    vector<city_t> cities;

    if (file.is_open()) {
        string line;
        while (getline(file, line, '\n')) {  // parse a line at a time

            stringstream ss{ line }; // remove expected :
            city_t city;
            string word;
            while (getline(ss, word, ',')) { //parse a line at a time

                int fieldidx = 1;
                if (word.find("[") != -1)
                    city.x = std::atoi(word.substr(1).c_str());
                else {
                    stringstream ss2{ word };
                    string field;
                    while (getline(ss2, field, '-')) {
                        field = field;
                        if (fieldidx == 1) {
                            city.y = std::atoi(field.c_str());
                        }
                        else
                            if (fieldidx == 2) {
                                city.city_ID = std::atoi(field.c_str());
                            }
                            else
                                if (fieldidx == 3) {
                                    city.city_name = field;
                                }
                        fieldidx++;
                    }

                }

            }
            cities.push_back(city);
        }
        file.close();
    }

    for (auto e : cities) {
        cout << e.x << "  " << e.y << "  " << e.city_ID << "  " << e.city_name << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: I apologise if my code is not very good. "x = " and "y = " is not in the text file. I tried to store the values i retrieve into x and y, but i am unable to store them into the variables.

Comment: @MistaJ: Edited

Answer (score 0):

My answer is more a workaround :

I don't think you really need to use multiple delimiters. It will add useless overhead to your program to parse them all.
Instead you can just say "The first parameter is x, the second is y, etc"
With this parsing it will result in getting an array from the line and accessing it with the correct index corresponding (you should use enum for this).

Answer (score 0):

{

```
string locationLine;  <br/>
while(getline(inputFile, locationLine))
{

    istringstream streamLine(locationLine);  <br/>
    string coordinates;  <br/>
    string city_ID;  <br/>
    string city_name;  <br/>

    getline(streamLine, coordinates, '-');  <br/>
    getline(streamLine, city_ID, '-');  <br/>
    getline(streamLine, city_name, '-');  <br/>

}
```

}

//Will need to code a function that reference the coordinates to //remove the '[' and ',' and ']'