# While I was printing the string, i have no idea what output is it

Tags: c++, string

My code is reading a file and using a delimiter to separate the text. Well, the previous part has no problem. I tried to convert the string into int when I separate the text line using delimiter "-". The separate part is also okay, but when I try to print the string, some weird things display on my terminal. I do not know what this is, do you guys have any idea?
My Text file format is [0,0]-93. I am using - as a delimiter.

[This is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfxy2.png)
I will show my code

```
ifstream myfile("mytext1.txt");
string line;
int a = 0;
int x = 0; 
int y = 0;
while(getline(myfile, line))
{
    //---------------------------------------------------------
    // tokenString is a String.
            // this is my function that using delimiter to separate the 
            // text file
    vector<string> tokenString = tokenizeString(line, "-");

    for(int i=0; i<tokenString.size(); i++)
        tokenString[i];
            //This is the part where the weird output comes from.
        cout << tokenString[1]; << endl;

    //converting id string to int
    stringstream geek(tokenString[1]);
    geek >> a;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean     for(int i=0; i<tokenString.size(); i++)
        cout << tokenString[1]; << endl;? This expression statement tokenString[i]; is redundant.

Comment: when I used the cout << tokenString[1] << endl;  It shows me the weird output

Comment: One more did you remove the statement tokenString[i]; ?

Comment: I want to change string into int using tokenString[1]. But when I use the geek >> a, it gives me the segmentation fault (core dumped) error, So I tried to see the output of the tokenString[1]. But it shows me the weird ouput. So I just want to know what is it.

Comment: I am repeating my question: did you remove the statement tokenString[i]; ? See your code     for(int i=0; i<tokenString.size(); i++)
        tokenString[i];
            //This is the part where the weird output comes from.
        cout << tokenString[1]; << endl;

Comment: oh So you mean that I do not need the tokenString[i] that in the for loop?

Comment: You are right. Remove it.

Comment: Then how can I access the tokenstring[1] part? Don't I have to initialize it first and access?

Comment: Sory i am learning a c++. So please understand me

Comment: Use in the loop this statement  cout << tokenString[i]; << endl; where the subscript operator uses the variable i

Comment: Have you checked that tokenString size is > 1 before accessing to the vector?

Comment: What I want to do is, I want to access the tokenString[1] to change to int. Since tokenString[1] is string!. So that is why I am using =  stringstream geek(tokenString[1]) geek >> a;

Comment: No I have not checkeddd.

Comment: @hoi MP if your vector is empty (or a single char), you read uninitialized memory (junk)

Comment: oh So it is an uninitialized memory?

Comment: Nico238, I have one question, why do i need to check the size of tokenString before I access to Vector?

Answer (score 0):

Hm, I am still not sure what the question is. And most answers have already been given in the comment.

Additionally, I remember the pattern of the source file lines. I have given an answer to [this questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57185791/reading-input-from-txt-file-with-different-kinds-of-delimiters/57189750#57189750) and have written a tokenizer for that.

I assume you want to do the same, because there is also a x andy, which are probably coordinates and then some ID.

However, maybe you are just selecting the ID after the '-' in your tokenizer. Then your vector of strings would just have the element 0. And this would lead to your problem. A `std::vector` has a function `at()` which will throw an error and tell you, when you try to access an out of bound value. You should use that instead of `tokenString[i];` (so,`tokenString.at(i);`).

Then you should understand 'blocks' of code, enclosed by curly braces. Your for loop just invokes the statement `tokenString[i];`, which does nothing. What should  `tokenString[i];` do?

So, if you want to do more things in a for loop, then use curly braces.

As said already, I am not sure what you want to achieve, but in my opinion you can delete your complete for loop. The compiler will optimze it away anyway.

Then you print `cout << tokenString[1]; << endl;`. I guest your vector has not 2 elments and hence you are printing random nonesense. Check the size of the vector, before accessing out of bounds values or use `at()`.

```
while(getline(myfile, line))
{
    //---------------------------------------------------------
    // tokenString is a String.
            // this is my function that using delimiter to separate the 
            // text file
    vector<string> tokenString = tokenizeString(line, "-");
    if (tokenString.size() > 1) {
        cout << tokenString[1]; << endl;

        //converting id string to int
        stringstream geek(tokenString[1]);
        geek >> a;
    }
    else {
        std::cerr << "Out of bounds\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all, really thank you for your help!!! .  so you mean that it is good to use "at()" if I am using in the for loop?

Comment: I want to access the id elements one by one! Do you know is there any way to access the id element?